# using ctags or cscope(without interactive mode) from commandline

Tags: ctags, cscope

I am using a custom editor for an embedded systems project. For source code I would like to get ctags working from command line and give me search results on commandline. Other option is to work with cscope in non interactive mode so I can include it in my editor at a later date. I did some initial web search but couldn't find anything relevant to accomplish this.

Does anyone know how to use either of these tools from command line?? Any tutorial?

Thanks.
Have a great day.

Comment: I don't like interactive mode, you can't build your own scripts on top of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using readtags.c shipped as part of ctags implementation, you can search a tag from given tags file.

Let me show an example:

```
$ ctags -R main
$ readtags -t tags kindDefinition
kindDefinition  main/types.h    /^typedef struct sKindDefinition kindDefinition;$/
$ readtags -t tags -e kindDefinition
kindDefinition  main/types.h    /^typedef struct sKindDefinition kindDefinition;$/;"    kind:t  typeref:struct:sKindDefinition
```

Comment: Thanks Masatake. I believe you are one of the developers/maintainers of ctag right? If so can I contact you in future for my effort? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am a developer of Universal-ctags. Github's issue tracker may be the best place to contact me about ctags.

Comment: Sounds great. I am watching Universal-ctags now and hopefully some day I can contribute to it too. For now I have only one question. Do we have any plan to provide a list of all functions called from any given function using ctags?? I use the one which comes from Ubuntu repo and I couldn't find a way to look up that information. Thanks Mr. Yamato.

Comment: No in short term.

Comment: Note: do not attempt to reuse a `tags` file created by something other than `universal-tags`'s implementation. You might get blank results.